# Error when creating entry into SQLdatabase

Tags: android

I keep getting this error

```
07-19 14:24:50.840: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1512): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 14:24:50.840: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at com.fttech.organizeit.TaskHelper.createLunch(TaskHelper.java:76)


07-19 14:24:50.840: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1512):     at com.fttech.organizeit.TaskDetails.saveState(TaskDetails.java:260)
```

Here is my createLunch()

```
}
    public long createTask(String title, String descrip, String type, String taskdatetime){
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DESCRIP, descrip);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, taskdatetime);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
```

It gives me a error at createLunch before saveState so im pretty sure the error lies here. Its pointing me to my return statement. i just dont see what the problem is.

Im seeing the lob.v for saved here. but not for inserted into database. i think the error lies here

```
Log.v(title, "saved");

    SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
    String taskdatetime = dateTimeFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());
    if(taskId == null){
        long id = helper.createTask(title, descrip, type, taskdatetime);
        Log.v(taskdatetime, "Inserted into databse");
        if(id >0){
            taskId = id;
        }
    }
    else{
        helper.updateTask(taskId, title, descrip, type, taskdatetime);
    }

    finish();


}
```

}

```
public void fillData(){
            helper.open();
            Cursor task = helper.fetchAllTask();
            startManagingCursor(task);

            String[] from = new String[]{TaskHelper.KEY_TITLE};
            int[] to = new int[]{R.layout.row};

            SimpleCursorAdapter taskAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list, task, from , to);
            setListAdapter(taskAdapter);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your mDB null? Try this and see if your id is returning as -1

```
public long createTask(String title, String descrip, String type, String taskdatetime){
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DESCRIP, descrip);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE_TIME, taskdatetime);

    long lResult=-1;
    if(mDB!=null)
    lResult = mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    return lResult;
}
```

**UPDATE**

You should open your database by calling the getWriteableDatabase method of your DatabaseHelper class which should be extend SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
mDB = myDataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase()
```

You should be checking the result of your call to createTask

```
   if(id >0){
        Log.v(taskdatetime, "Inserted into databse");
        taskId = id;
   }
   else
   {
        Log.v(taskdatetime, "Insert failed");
   }
```

Comment: This works but it doesn't populate in my list after its saved?

Comment: That means that you are not opening your database.

Comment: I posted a snippet of code at the bottom of my question. in my filldata method i opened the database there. That is the method that populates my list

Comment: Everything returned in the log cat. Everything was inserted but my list list doesnt populate

Comment: I posted another question about this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749850/how-to-inflate-a-linearlayout-as-a-row/6750190#6750190

Answer (score 1):

Yoshi,

From the code the only thing that jumps out is the mDB object. Did you declare it somewhere else in the class.  If not then that's your problem.  If so what is line 76.  Could you post that.

In case you need it.  Here's a snippet of code declaring the Mdb:

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
            super(context, DBConstants.DATABASE_NAME, null, DBConstants.DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            //db.execSQL(DBConstants.TABLE_CREATE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVerison)
        {
            //db.execSQL(DATABASE_UPGRADE);

        }
    }

//Open the data base.  It will either create or upgrade the database
public DbAdpt open() throws android.database.SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
```

Hope this helps,
George