# How to inflate a linearlayout as a row?

Tags: android

I am trying to populate a list of items from a database. 
I want to inflate a linearLayout as the row instead of a regular row to show a imageView.

Here is my XML for My row.xml linearLayout.

```
  ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="4dip">
      <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop = "true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
           />
           <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
        android:textColor="#15317E"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="21dip"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            />




        </LinearLayout>
             </LinearLayout>
```

Now Here i use a SimpleCursorAdapter to show the layout in the list.xml

```
public void fillData(){
            helper.open();
            Cursor task = helper.fetchAllTask();
            startManagingCursor(task);

            String[] from = new String[]{TaskHelper.KEY_TITLE};
            int[] to = new int[]{R.layout.row};

            SimpleCursorAdapter taskAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list, task, from , to);
            setListAdapter(taskAdapter);

        }
```

Im not sure if im doing this right, If someone is familiar with this. please let me know. 
Thanks

In my fillData() i would like to show imageView in it as icon also. But it wont populate for some reason everytime i add a item. Maybe its a better way i can reconstruct the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
String[] from = new String[]{TaskHelper.KEY_TITLE};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.title};
SimpleCursorAdapter taskAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, 
    task, from , to);
```

Comment: My list still returned empty after created a item for the list. It shows my list:emoty = "There is no item."

Answer (score 0):

1. Use MarvinLabs answer.
2. Make sure that the cursor 'task' in not empty.
3. - Try call `setListAdapter(taskAdapter)` in GUI thread if you call `fillData` in background thread
   - after, try ListView's 'invalidate' or 'postInvalidate' method

Comment: I added a Log method to the fillData and the method gets called sucessfully but no data is populated in the list.